# Using quoted variables in a custom dplyr wrapper function

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyselect

My problem is the following. I have a function `foo` which works inside `dplyr::mutate`. This function accepts `tidyselect` syntax. I want to build a wrapper function `bar` which should also support `tidyselect` syntax. I am looking for a clean way to pass the `tidyselect`ed columns from `bar` to `foo`. Sounds easy, but the problem is that `foo` needs to accept bare user input which will be quoted and it also need to accept already quoted columns which come from the wrapper function.

So lets have a look at the problem:

```r
library(dplyr)

myiris <- as_tibble(iris)

# this is a minimal function supporting tidyselect
# its a toy function, which just returns the tidyselected columns 

foo <- function(cols){
  data <- cur_data()
  vars <- tidyselect::eval_select(rlang::enquo(cols),  data)
  out <- data[, vars]
  
  names(out) <- paste0("new_", names(out))
  out
}

# the function is working:
myiris %>%
  mutate(foo(c(Sepal.Length)))
#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new_Sepal.Length
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>              <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa               5.1
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa               4.9
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa               4.7
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa               4.6
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa               5  
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa               5.4
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa               4.6
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa               5  
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa               4.4
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa               4.9
#> # … with 140 more rows

# this is a wrapper function around `foo`
bar <- function(df, .cols) {
  .cols <- rlang::enquo(.cols)
  mutate(df, foo(.cols))
}

# this will throw an error
myiris %>%
  bar(Sepal.Length)

#> Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
#> ℹ Use `all_of(.cols)` instead of `.cols` to silence this message.
#> ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
#> This message is displayed once per session.
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
#> x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
#> x Subscript has the wrong type `quosure/formula`.
#> ℹ It must be numeric or character.
#> ℹ Input `..1` is `foo(.cols)`.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It makes total sense that the above doesn't work. Not obvious to me is how to handle this problem in a clean and consistent way.

Below I show what I have tried and what kind of mediocre workaround I came up with.

What I thought I could do is: to check if the columns are already quoted, and if not `enquote` them. However, this does not seem to be possible. Once the unquoted columns are used for any kind of operation they will be evaluated and change. The `enquo` has to happen as first thing. But if it happens first, I can't check if they have been quoted already.

```r
# we would need to check in foo
# if cols is already quoted or not
# but this seems not to be possible
# since `cols` changes, once it is used / touched

foo <- function(cols){
  data <- cur_data()
  if (!rlang::is_quosure(cols)) {
    cols <- enquo(cols)
  }
  vars <- tidyselect::eval_select(cols, data)
  out <- data[, vars]
  
  names(out) <- paste0("new_", names(out))
  out
}

# not working
iris %>%
  mutate(foo(c(Sepal.Length)))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
#> x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
#> x Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
#> ℹ Input `..1` is `foo(c(Sepal.Length))`.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

At the moment I am using a workaround that I don't like very much. I use the ellipsis `...` in `foo` so that I can call it with an additional argument which does not need to be documented. Now `foo` can be called with a `flag` argument and in that case `foo` knows that the columns don't have to be quoted.

However, I don't think this is a clean solution. I would prefer some kind of function which quotes if not already quoted, or a function which restores the environment of the columns names when they are passed to `bar`.

One other possible solution would be to first evaluate the columns in `bar` and then paste the column name as strings to `foo`. I haven't tried that, it should work since tidyselect accepts strings, however I would like to avoid evaluating the column names in `bar` as it doesn't seem very performant.

Any other ideas welcome.

```r
# workaround using `...`
foo <- function(cols, ...){
  
  dots <- rlang::list2(...)
  if (is.null(dots$flag)) {
    cols <- enquo(cols)
  }
  
  data <- cur_data()
  vars <- tidyselect::eval_select(cols, data)
  out <- data[, vars]
  
  names(out) <- paste0("new_", names(out))
  out
}

bar <- function(df, .cols) {
  .cols <- rlang::enquo(.cols)
  mutate(df, foo(.cols, flag = TRUE))
}


# working
myiris %>%
  mutate(foo(c(Sepal.Length)))

#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new_Sepal.Length
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>              <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa               5.1
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa               4.9
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa               4.7
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa               4.6
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa               5  
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa               5.4
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa               4.6
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa               5  
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa               4.4
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa               4.9
#> # … with 140 more rows

# working
myiris %>%
  bar(Sepal.Length)

#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new_Sepal.Length
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>              <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa               5.1
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa               4.9
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa               4.7
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa               4.6
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa               5  
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa               5.4
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa               4.6
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa               5  
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa               4.4
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa               4.9
#> # … with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the use case, but why do the columns have to be quoted when you pass them from `bar()` to `foo()`? If you unquote the input, everything works as intended:

```
bar <- function(df, .cols) {
  .cols <- rlang::enquo(.cols)
  mutate(df, foo(!!.cols))      # <--- unquote before passing to foo()
}

# Or alternatively
bar <- function(df, .cols) {mutate(df, foo( {{.cols}} ))}

myiris %>%
  bar(Sepal.Length)             # works
```

Comment: I could swear that I tried this, and it threw an error, but apparently its working and I must have got something wrong somewhere else when I checked it. Thanks for solving this.